# Angular 2 ngFor different types in prime-ng data list

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have an array of type "any", wich is filled with dynamic data:

```
let history: any = [];
history.push({ grouped_date: "Week No. 12", isHeader: true });
history.push({ activity: "go to work", project: "intern project" });
history.push({ activity: "eat some food", project: "no project" });
```

so I want to display my data different, if the item is type of the "grouped date".

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items">
  <li>
    <div *ngIf="item.isHeader" style="background-color: #882346;">
        Week: {{item.grouped_date}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="item.activity != null" style="background-color: #fff;">
        activity: {{item.activity}}
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

but the problem is, the list always shows the first div-container. so the sample above shows three times "Week: Week No. 12". How can iterate through a list like that to show some lines as "divider"?

**Update:**

Okay thats weird, the answer from Wassim Chegham works very well. So I will be more specific (I just use a small example to break down the problem).

I use [PrimeNG DataList](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/components/datalist/datalist.ts), which is a component for displaying data in a list view. The source code just use the same way like the sample above:

```
<div class="ui-datalist-content ui-widget-content">
            <ul class="ui-datalist-data">
                 <li *ngFor="let item of dataToRender">
                            <template [pTemplateWrapper]="itemTemplate" [item]="item"></template>
                </li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

(see the link for complete source code). But the data displays wrong, like described above. What's wrong here and how could I use prime-ng for displaying the data correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The code you submitted seems to be OK. It even does what you asked for.
Here is the complete example:

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ul *ngFor="let item of history">
  <li>
    <div *ngIf="item.isHeader" style="background-color: #882346;">
        Week: {{item.grouped_date}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="item.activity != null" style="background-color: #fff;">
        activity: {{item.activity}}
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
  `,
})
export class App {
  history:any;
  constructor() {
    this.history = [];
    this.history.push({ grouped_date: "Week No. 12", isHeader: true });
    this.history.push({ activity: "go to work", project: "intern project" });
    this.history.push({ activity: "eat some food", project: "no project" });
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ycL1nQrKpjNsOMtDoijE?p=preview

Comment: wow, thats weird, your right. I update my question for be more specific, cause I use prime-ng which use just *ngFor, but displaying the data wrong.